# Cannot install simplexml extension on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu, amazon-s3, simplexml

I'm running php5.6 on ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to upload files to an s3 bucket following steps from aws. When running the code I am getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found in .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Parser/PayloadParserTrait.php on line 44
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() .../upload_to_s3.php:0
PHP   2. upload_to_s3() .../upload_to_s3.php:75
PHP   3. Aws\S3\S3Client->putObject() .../upload_to_s3.php:66
PHP   4. Aws\AwsClient->__call() .../upload_to_s3.php:66
PHP   5. Aws\AwsClient->execute() .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php:86
PHP   6. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait() .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php:58
PHP   7. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:62
PHP   8. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:226
PHP   9. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:269
PHP  10. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:226
PHP  11. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:269
PHP  12. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:224
PHP  13. GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler->execute() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:248
PHP  14. GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler->tick() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php:145
PHP  15. GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php:118
PHP  16. GuzzleHttp\Promise\RejectedPromise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php:48
PHP  17. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/RejectedPromise.php:42
PHP  18. GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:169
PHP  19. Aws\WrappedHttpHandler->Aws\{closure}() .../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:204
PHP  20. Aws\WrappedHttpHandler->parseError() .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php:101
PHP  21. call_user_func:{.../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php:178}() .../vendor/aws/aw    s-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php:178
PHP  22. Aws\Api\ErrorParser\XmlErrorParser->__invoke() .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php:178
PHP  23. Aws\Api\ErrorParser\XmlErrorParser->parseXml() .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/ErrorParser/XmlErrorParser.php:42
```

I have tried install php-xml and get this:

```
php-xml is already the newest version (1:7.1+55+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
```

Trying to install a specific version ie. apt install php5.6-xml doesn't find packages and the simplexml.conf file is missing from mods-available.

I have a simplexml.ini in /etc/php/7.0/mods-available and have tried switching to php7.0 to try and correct these issues to no avail.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you do `php -m | grep xml`, what do you get?

Comment: the output is ```libxml```

Comment: Have you installed libxml?

Comment: This is what I get from trying to install libxml ```E: Unable to locate package libxml```

Comment: It might be libxml2. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/733169/how-to-install-libxml2-in-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: Says it's already installed ```libxml2 is already the newest version (2.9.4-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+2).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm3.8
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Note the simplexml extension shows as `SimpleXML` in the `php -m` output, so you want `php -m | grep -i xml` to determine if it's enabled.

Comment: The only output from that is still just ```libxml``` and when looking at the list of enable extensions, simplexml is not there

Comment: If you do `ls $(php-config --extension-dir)` do you see `simplexml.so`?

Comment: Tried that and got: ```The program 'php-config' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install php7.0-dev
``` tried that command and: ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-dev : Depends: libpcre3-dev but it is not going to be installed. E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.``` tried to install libpcre3-dev and got: ```libpcre3-dev : Depends: libpcre3 (= 2:8.38-3.1) but 2:8.41-1.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.``` And libpcre3 is current

Comment: Ok well I think the bottom line is that you're using a really old version of PHP on a really old version of Ubuntu. The sury.org PPAs have been dropped for 16.04, so if you didn't already have all the required files installed, you're probably not going to get them now. Your best course of action is likely going to be updating to a reasonably modern version of Ubuntu and PHP.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case, but thought it would ultimately be. Really appreciate the feedback, I'll work on an update or explore other options.

Answer (score 0):

Found out my problem was with my aws user key. I was using the wrong key and it kept throwing this error. If anyone comes across this same issue, double check your key and hopefully you can save yourself the headache. No extensions needed to be installed to get it to work properly.